# Laravel Many To Many Relationship with unwanted limit of 250

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-7

I've a Many To Many Relationship

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string

apps
    id - integer
    steam_id - integer (ID for this app on steam)
    name - string

app_user
    user_id - integer
    app_id - integer
```

My user modal

```php
    public function apps()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App::class, 'app_user');
    }
```

My app modal

```php
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'app_user');
    }
```

Now I want to output the apps from a user, which basically works in several methods.

```php
$user->apps()->get()

$user->apps()->inRandomOrder()->get();

$user->apps()->orderBy('name')->get()

$user->apps()->limit(50)->get()
```

But no matter what I do, I always get only 250 entries back, although this user has 1072 entries. Where is this limit 250 set and how can I increase or decrease it?

Comment: In your App model you have $this->belongsToMany(App::class, 'app_user'); for your users relationship, just as a heads up. Shouldn't be causing your issue though.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no "250 row limit" anywhere in laravel, so you have an interesting bug happening somewhere in your code, or less likely the framework is not handling some weird edge case of your setup.

Comment: It's a fresh Laravel installation. Only laravel/socialite and socialiteproviders/steam were installed, everything else is unchanged.

Comment: Yah, so likely you have a bug somewhere. Only other thing I can think of is if you have configured your db with some sort of limit. I am like 98% sure this is not a laravel config issue.

Comment: I once set the current code to public. I will test a little bit now, otherwise I will just build the query as raw.

Comment: Does $user->apps()->limit(50)->get() return 250 records too?

Comment: $user->apps()->limit(50)->get()  returns 50 records and  $user->apps()->limit(1000)->get() returns 250 records.

Comment: what does $user->apps()->where('id', 1000)->first() return? (1000 = some app id in your db higher than the first 250 records)

Comment: $user->apps()->where('id', 1000)->first()  returns null. It will output all where id has 2 or 3 digits, but not those which have 4 or more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217644/discussion-between-kurt-friars-and-norman-huth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was once again quite simple. Kurt Friars gave me the right mental impulse..
I adapted the migration for the overview and my mistake was that I used the ID of Steam with ->sync([]) and not the ID of the apps table.

Thank you all and have a nice weekend.